# CosmosDb Direct w/ TCP

Tags: azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I have a function app that reads / writes to CosmosDb, and if i use the following ConnectionPolicy, we achieve only a few connections ~20-30 ..

```
connPolicy = new ConnectionPolicy
{
    ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Gateway,
    RetryOptions = retryOptions
};
```

some of these connections are probably also ApplicationInsights, as well as EventHub Trigger connections?/ (not sure who it works in detail)

but if we use this code, as recommended here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/performance-tips#networking

```
connPolicy = new ConnectionPolicy
{
    ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Direct,
    ConnectionProtocol = Protocol.Tcp,
    RetryOptions = retryOptions
};
```

there are pushing 250 - 300 "connections" for the same run of data... this quickly raises exceptions when running on consumption plan..

i do not understand how a more "optimal" configuration can cause this, as it means that we will likely need to move to App Service Plan to accommodate it, this seems backwards.

** Added Example Function **

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using System;

namespace Test.Functions
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log)
        {
            log.Info($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");

            var obj = new NewClass();
            obj.DoAllTheWork();
        }
    }

    internal class NewClass
    {
        private static CosmosHelper repo;

        internal void DoAllTheWork()
        {
            // do work..
            // do work..

            repo = new CosmosHelper();
            repo.SaveADocument();

            // do something else..
            // do something else..

            repo.SaveADocument();

            // do something else..
        }
    }

    public class CosmosHelper
    {
        private static readonly object constructionLock = new object();
        public static DocumentClient client;

        public CosmosHelper()
        {
            lock (constructionLock)
            {
                // .. get some properties.
                if (client == null) client = new DocumentClient(...);
            }
        }

        internal void SaveADocument()
        {
            client.UpsertDocumentAsync(...);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Explain what do you mean by "connections". The documentclient should have a single connection which pushes TCP packets. It shouldn't initiate 250-300 different connections.

Comment: to measure these connections i am looking in the metrics for the function app in question, and choosing connections from the left hand side.. the only change that i am making to test this is modify our ConnectionPolicy in our connection helper class.. i appreciate that some of these connections will therefore probably be ApplicationInsights, and probs a connection to EventHub trigger perhaps... they are not all CosmosDb

Comment: Could you add a full function where you instantiate Cosmos client(s)?

Comment: @Mikhail done, that is highly simplified, the idea being that we make the DocumentClient and then share it anywhere we can do var repo = new CosmosHelper()

Comment: additional thought... i am not explictly disposing of anything when querying the CosmosDb... should i be??

Answer (score 0):

Best practices for using Cosmos DB in Azure Functions:

- Create a single static client to avoid running out of sockets. The client will be safely shared between executions over time and in parallel.
- Use Gateway Mode, not Direct Mode, if you're running on Consumption. The latter mode creates a lot of outbound connections by design (which is why you're seeing the order of magnitude increase.)

Re: disposing, DocumentClient implements IDisposable, so it can be handled in the usual ways. Keeping it long-lived is still a good idea because even if IDisposable gets rid of the object, it takes a while for the OS to free up the sockets.

Comment: ok, so re: point #1 as far as i'm aware this is exactly what we are doing, just we have it in another class.. the Gateway on Consumption is interesting, and not something i have read or seem recommended anywhere.. is there are doco on this?

Comment: Not at present; that advice comes directly from the Cosmos team. This is a gap in our documentation, though, and we'll be filling it in.

Answer (score 0):

Please create a `static` instance of the class that has the Cosmos DB client, [you are running out of connections](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Managing-Connections) because you are increasingly creating clients constantly.

You have a `static` within `NewClass` but you are creating `NewClass` on every execution and inside, you are doing a `new CosmosHelper` every time. Try to move it like this:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using System;

namespace Test.Functions
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        private static CosmosHelper cosmosHelper = new CosmosHelper();
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log)
        {
            log.Info($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");

            var obj = new NewClass();
            obj.DoAllTheWork(cosmosHelper);
        }
    }

    internal class NewClass
    {
        internal void DoAllTheWork(CosmosHelper repo)
        {
            // do work..
            // do work..

            repo.SaveADocument();

            // do something else..
            // do something else..

            repo.SaveADocument();

            // do something else..
        }
    }

    public class CosmosHelper
    {
        private static readonly object constructionLock = new object();
        public static DocumentClient client;

        public CosmosHelper()
        {
            lock (constructionLock)
            {
                // .. get some properties.
                if (client == null) client = new DocumentClient(...);
            }
        }

        internal void SaveADocument()
        {
            client.UpsertDocumentAsync(...);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What I ultimately was trying to achieve was that anywhere a connection to the Db was required, it could attempt to make a new CosmosHelper client, but then always get back the same DocumentClient as that was static.. I potentially have got in a spot of confusion though.. i shall investigate! Ty.

Comment: Now that you mention your idea, maybe it is running into some race condition with the lock and creating many DocumentClients?